# CNTLM proxy and .pac file

Tags: proxy, ntlm, proxy.pac

Is there a way to use CNTLM proxy with autoconfiguration .pac file? I'd like CNTLM to automatically decide, which urls should be resolved through proxy and which directly (basing on a remote corporate .pac file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CNTLM can't process PAC files. You could try to configure CNTLM so that it contains the same set of proxies as your PAC file, but some PAC files are too complex to represent with CNTLM's config settings, and you also risk your CNTLM config file getting out-of-sync with updates that your network admins make to your PAC file.

An alternative is to use [Alpaca](https://github.com/samuong/alpaca), which executes the PAC file in a JavaScript VM, and performs NTLM authentication with the resulting proxy.